# SQL table design for ISCO / International Standard Classification of Occupations

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to insert International Standard Classification of Occupations into MySQL.

Here is detailed info about categories:
http://www.ilo.org/wcmsp5/groups/public/---dgreports/---dcomm/---publ/documents/publication/wcms_172572.pdf

Also I found a github project:
https://github.com/patriciomacadden/isco/blob/master/db/schema.rb
It seems to use separate tables per different levels of groups.

My current opinion is to make a single table and store some duplicate data since the data wont change often and amount of the data is less than thousand rows. For example:

```
'l1','l2','l3','l4' are 'TINYINT' and 'level','name' are VARCHAR. So 'level' is the primary key

l1  |l2  |l3  |l4  |level|name
----|----|----|----|-----|--------
5   |null|null|null|5    |Services and Sales Workers
5   |1   |null|null|51   |Personal Services Workers
5   |1   |1   |null|511  |Travel Attendants, Conductors Guides
5   |1   |1   |1   |5111 |Travel Attendants and Travel Stewards
5   |1   |1   |2   |5112 |Transport Conductors
5   |1   |1   |3   |5113 |Travel Guides
```

The 'level' field is varchar because I may need to get all rows including the top category.

> WHERE level LIKE '511%'

I am not sure if it is better to have 'level' as int but perhaps varchar has better characteristics also when sorting this specific data.

I am not sure if I need the l1,l2,l3,l4 separately but with so few rows, it does not really hurt perhaps to have some redundancy.

So, the question is, do you see any obvious errors in my design? Would you be able to improve on this?

I am not sure if I need to beware of more fields because I did not finish reading that ISCO pdf yet...

Thanks

Comment: That is a 433 page PDF, perhaps explain in abstract terms what you want.  That said the L values should almost certainly be vertical and one would prefer to avoid a "summary" column that duplicates data already on the row  (with an incorrect datatype).

Comment: Well, I want to import ISCO into SQL in the best way possible. Is it abstract enough? :) You are right about L fields and probably I do not need them at all. But I was worried that there may be cases which I cant think of right now, where they may prove to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both l1/l2/l3/l4 and level: these are completely redundant. Storing the same data in two different ways just creates the possibility that somewhere along the line a mistake will make them inconsistent, and then you get weird results. A query that use l1/2/3/4 finds different records than a query that uses level, and users are baffled why their results don't make sense. Like, if the data entry screen uses level and you have code to break it into l1/2/3/4, a user runs a query that under the table uses l1/2/3/4 and it finds zero matching records. Then he looks at the screen and the record is right there! Or worse, totals don't add up, etc.

It's hard to say which of the two to prefer. Most queries are probably easier to write with the single field: select blah blah where level='512', or select blah blah were level like '51%', rather then select blah blah where l1=5 and l2=1 and l3=2 and l4 is null, etc. Oh, and testing lower levels without referencing higher levels is probably meaningless. That is, when would you ever say select blah blah where l2=4 but not test l1?

Level should surely be a string and not an integer. You want '51' to sort before '512', not after. You would never do arithmetic on these, right? What would it mean to say chemist.level + teacher.level, or clerk.level * 3?

Answer (score 1):

I would do

- `level VARCHAR(4) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  (A glance at the PDF seems to say that 4 is sufficient, but increase the "4" if necessary.)  `VARCHAR` will sort 'correctly', `INT` will not.
- `SUBSTR(level, 3, 1)` to get the equivalent of l3, if you need to display such.
- The `SUBSTR` will give you an empty string instead of `NULL`; you can use `IF(,)` or `CASE...` to render it whatever way you like.